# Is there any way to transfer money in multichain without creating asset each time?

Tags: blockchain

I am developing a "currency transfer system" using multichain. Suppose, we have 4 parties in the multichain having some balances. I need to transfer some balances among them. so is there any way to transfer money without creating asset each time?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.multichain.com/developers/json-rpc-api/

If you look under "Sending one-way payments," you will see `send` can do exactly what you wish. This can send either assets or the native currency.

`send address amount` is all it takes!

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)